# Is there a way to use postman or vs code thunder client with a google service account?

Tags: rest, postman, service-accounts

I would like to play around with the google calendar api and my service account before I begin writing something to add events to my calendar. Is there a way to use something like postman for this? My understanding is that there is no callback url since no user authorization is required. However the vs code thunder client requires it for OAuth2.0.

Should I be using a different Auth type? Or am I just going about this the wrong way?